# Accessing Acer SNID via Windows WMI?

Tags: wmi, licensing

Dell have been really helpful in making their desktop and laptop serial numbers available via WMI. Has anyone had any success in finding similar information about Acer computers, especially the SNID, by similar means. If so, how?

Context: Windows Server 2003

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preferred way of discovering what is available via WMI is to run [scriptomatic2](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=12028) on that machine and browse the WMI classes, and run the scripts within the app.

Comment: Yeah, that's a pretty good way of doing it. I prefer to use SoftPerfect's free NetScan utility. That way I can apply a WMI query to large slabs of the network. I was just hoping to find the "magic" query that would save me trying every combination of object and item.

Comment: Serial number should be in win32_bios, but I'm not familiar with "SNID".

Comment: It is indeed in Win32_BIOS. And as for SNID, there's a way given on Acer's Support site for calculating the SNID from serial number. All good. Thanks for your help.